# Fastest way to find last occurence of a character in line?

Tags: cursor-motions, find, count

Say we have the following:

```
echo 'This is a test'.$test1.$test2.$test3.$test4.$test5.'and this is another test';
                      ^
```

With the cursor being on the first dollar sign, and I want to change everything between all dots:

```
echo 'This is a test'..'and this is another test';
                      ^
```

what is the fastest way to do this? Preferably using `f`, `F`, `t`, `T`.

`c5t.` works, but requires you to count exactly how many dots there are. Unfortunately, something like `c99t.` simply won't work—it won't skip to the last dot.

Comment: I would go with `c/..and<CR>` Using search to match two characters before `and`. Actually that could even be `c/..a<CR>` if we are playing vimgolf. But that doesn't work in all the cases.

Comment: `v$T.c`? But I remember having answered with a text object for these kind of manipulations in the past :/ ...

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! Thanks for the [edit]!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I find it is best to not get too wrapped up in optimizing for minimal keystrokes, but instead learning & using motions effectively. Sometimes this means multiple motions, multiple operations, and even using ex-commands. The best way is typically what keeps you doing your work and not thinking about golfing your key strokes

Let's look at some ways to accomplish your goal

- `cf5` - uses `f` to find the `5` character. Great for this exact case, but not general
- Using `v`, `t.`, and `;` - Builds up the visual selection and repeat `t.` motion with `;`. Simple but does require hammering the `;` key
- `ct.` then do `d;` or `v;` to clean up the line (repeat with `.`/`;` as needed)
- `ci'` - Two dots are easy to type, so just change everything inside the quotes
- Use `/` to search directly. e.g. `c/.*\zs\.<cr>`
- `v$F.lc` - Use visual mode and search from end of line with `F`
- `v$?.\.<cr>c` - Use `?` to search backwards from end of line
- `:s/\.\zs.*\ze\./replace/` - substitute using `\zs` & `\ze`
- etc

Ultimately which ever way you remember is best. I think using `ci'` and `vt.;;;;c` would probably fit with how I think best. Using `/` would be ideal if the search is easy. Another consideration is if you are going to repeat this change then finding the ideal motion or pattern would change.